# UITableViewCell out of bounds but in debugging has bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a `tableView` section for each day in my app. In simulator when I add data from beginning (tableview empty) it shows OK all the data, the section's name is the day, everything OK but when I change the date from my settings and add a new input I get an error that when I create the cell, it's out of bounds. I set some prints to see if its out of bounds and it seems to be in bounds but I don't know why I get this error

**Code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expenseCell") as? ExpenseCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
      print("SECTION: \(daySections[indexPath.section].daySection)")
      print("ROWS: \(daySections[indexPath.section].contentCount)")
      let budget = userBudget[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] // <- error getting here
      cell.delegate = self
      cell.configureCell(budget: budget)
      return cell
  }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  Int(daySections[section].contentCount)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return daySections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return daySections[section].daySection
}
```

**Debug:**

```
SECTION: Optional("21.10.2017")
ROWS: 2
SECTION: Optional("21.10.2017")
ROWS: 2
SECTION: Optional("22.10.2017")
ROWS: 1
fatal error: Index out of range
2017-10-16 15:41:30.284173+0300 Expense Manager[7877:380262] fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

I also set prints to show me `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` and when I get the error they are section: 1; row: 0.

Comment: If userBudget is an array. I think this array does not exist items at desired index.  

```Index out of range``` occurs because you tried to access an element in a array, using a numeric index that exceeds the array's boundaries. You should check boundaries of array before getting item.

Comment: userBudget is an array of arrays of CoreData object " let userBudget : [[Budget]] = []"

Comment: Add this before `let budget =...` `dump(userBudget[indexPath.section])`

Comment: From a data management point of view, it's usually a very bad idea to use one array (or other data element) to calculate `numberOfRowsInSection ` and a different one for actually populating the views for the rows.  Switching to the same data structure for both will likely simplify life.

Comment: @Ladislav still not working.

Comment: @PhillipMills well it really is. I cannot fix this code so I will try and rewrite the code using only Budget entity, without the Date entity.

Comment: The dump comad is ment so that you copy and paste what you get in the console and show us what you have in each userBudget

Comment: Oh. That was something I didn't know. I'm sorry. Thank you for telling me, I didn't know. I already checked out my code from Git and I'm trying another strategy. Thank you for helping.